# SharedPreferences not working to retrieve int value

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I had some problem with sharedpreferences in my project that is the sharedpreferences not receive int value from another activity

there is a two class: `menu.class` and `levelone.class`

I had the following code like this in my `menu.class`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
        editor.putInt("Lifes", 6);
        editor.putInt("Hints", 6);          
        editor.putInt("Level", 1);  
        editor.commit();

     f1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f1);

     f2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f2);
     f2lock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.f2lock);


   f1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i =new Intent(menu.this, levelone.class);
                startActivity(i);             
            }             
        }); 

    f2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              Intent i =new Intent(menu.this, leveltwo.class);
              startActivity(i);          
            }             
      });

    f3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f3);
    f3lock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.f3lock);

 //this the code to receive int value from another activity

   levelunlocked = pref.getInt("Level", 0); 

   if(levelunlocked == 2)

    {
        f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if(levelunlocked == 3)

    {
        f3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        f3lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }   
}
```

i had this code in `levelone.class` to get the default value from `menu.class`

```
int gamelifes, gamehints, gamelevel, index=0; 


SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE);
gamelifes = pref.getInt("Lifes", 0);
gamehints = pref.getInt("Hints", 0);
gamelevel = pref.getInt("Level", 0);

//the value from sharedpreferences is use to be a text by use code below

lifes1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lifestext1);
lifes1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
lifes1.setText(String.valueOf(gamelifes));   

hints1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hintstext1);
hints1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
hints1.setText(String.valueOf(gamehints));
```

and to save the sharedpreferences with new data

```
String answer=edittextanswer1.getText().toString();              
            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer1[index]))
            {
                gamelevel++;                
                image.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                finishbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
                editor.putInt("Lifes", gamelifes);
                editor.putInt("Hints", gamehints);          
                editor.putInt("Level", gamelevel);  
                editor.commit();
            else
            {    
            tryagain1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            gamelifes--;
            lifes1.setText(String.valueOf(gamelifes));
            }
```

then if finish button is clicked it will be like this

```
    finishbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v){
              finish();
          }
       });
```

so `levelone.class` are finish and back to `menu.class`

but the sharedpreferences retrieve value code not working

```
//this the code to receive int value from another activity

   levelunlocked = pref.getInt("Level", 0); 

   if(levelunlocked == 2)

    {
        f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if(levelunlocked == 3)

    {
        f3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        f3lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }   
}
```

can anyone give some solution to this?

Comment: You get old values ?

Comment: what values are you getting everywhere?. Is there some sort of log?. I really think there should be a better way to do this rather than using preferences?.

Comment: Tell us what value are you getting?

Comment: Try using editor.apply() instead of editor.commit().

Comment: sorry my explanation incomplete, i have updated my question more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the retrieval code in `onCreate()`. This method won't be called when you are coming to activity `menu` from `levalone`.

Add the following code in `onResume()`

```
//this the code to receive int value from another activity

levelunlocked = pref.getInt("Level", 0); 

if(levelunlocked == 2)
{
    f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
if(levelunlocked == 3)
{
    f3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    f3lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: you mean is this?  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: there is 2 onCreate method in there, so did i have to change both of them ?

Comment: Just delete the code I have mentioned from the method and put it in `onResume()`

Comment: its work bro, thank you so much! maybe you can help me with my new question about Sharedpreferences too in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050420/sharedpreferences-not-save-if-the-application-is-re-open