# SharedPreferences not Save if the application is re-open

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

My sharedpreferences does not save if i re-open my game the data that i saved before with SharedPreferences are not load, setting on my current activity is back to normal again or default

this is the image of my button in `menu.class`

[image]

this is the following code of my `menu.class`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
    editor.putInt("Lifes", 6);
    editor.putInt("Hints", 6);          
    editor.putInt("Level", 1);  
    editor.commit();

     f1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f1);

     f2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f2);
     f2lock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.f2lock);


   f1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i =new Intent(menu.this, levelone.class);
                startActivity(i);             
            }             
        }); 

    f2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              Intent i =new Intent(menu.this, leveltwo.class);
              startActivity(i);          
            }             
      });

    f3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f3);
    f3lock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.f3lock);

}
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();

   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
   levelunlocked = pref.getInt("Level", 0); 

   if(levelunlocked == 2)

    {
        f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if(levelunlocked == 3)

    {
        f3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        f3lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }   

       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
       editor.putInt("Level", levelunlocked);
       editor.commit();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splashscreen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and i had this code in `levelone.class` to get the default value from `menu.class`

```
int gamelifes, gamehints, gamelevel, index=0; 


SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE);
gamelifes = pref.getInt("Lifes", 0);
gamehints = pref.getInt("Hints", 0);
gamelevel = pref.getInt("Level", 0);

//the value from sharedpreferences is use to be a text by use code below

lifes1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lifestext1);
lifes1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
lifes1.setText(String.valueOf(gamelifes));   

hints1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hintstext1);
hints1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
hints1.setText(String.valueOf(gamehints));
```

and to save the sharedpreferences with new data

```
String answer=edittextanswer1.getText().toString();              
            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer1[index]))
            {
                gamelevel++;                
                image.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                finishbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
                editor.putInt("Lifes", gamelifes);
                editor.putInt("Hints", gamehints);          
                editor.putInt("Level", gamelevel);  
                editor.commit();
            else
            {    
            tryagain1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            gamelifes--;
            lifes1.setText(String.valueOf(gamelifes));
            }
```

then if finish button is clicked it will be like this

```
finishbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v){
          finish();
      }
   });
```

so `levelone.class` are finish and back to `menu.class`

[image]

and SharedPreferences code its worked properly, every button in `my menu.class` work with the code and be visible!

but if i exit the application, its back to normal again

[image]

anyone have a solution to fix my problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing is, on your `onCreate()` method you're **always** resetting the shared preferences here:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
editor.putInt("Lifes", 6);
editor.putInt("Hints", 6);          
editor.putInt("Level", 1);  
editor.commit();
```

Just check if this file exists already before that line with an `if` statement. That should do the trick.

Something like:

```
if (pref.contains("Level")) {
    // Do not reset
}
else {
    // Create the prefs
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
    editor.putInt("Lifes", 6);
    editor.putInt("Hints", 6);          
    editor.putInt("Level", 1);  
    editor.commit();
}
```

You don't have to check for that exact field, it's just an example. Adjust it for your needs and game logic.

Take a look at the `Activity` lifecycle to understand why this is happening.

[image]

(diagram [source](http://web.archive.org/web/20140218132043/http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html))

Everytime you open your app, the `onCreate()` method is called, so your prefs get reset before you read them.

More on the lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

**EDIT:** The following snippet shows one way to solve your problem.

```
public static final String PREF_LIFES = "Lifes";
public static final String PREF_HINTS = "Hints";
public static final String PREF_LEVEL = "Level";
public static final String PREF_IS_SET = "isSet";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 

    // Check wether the pref is set or not.
    if (pref.getBoolean(PREF_IS_SET.false)) {
        // The prefs is set. Do some game logic here. Like checking for lifes.
        if (pref.getInt(PREF_LIFES,0) == 0) {
            // Player is "dead", reset it.
            resetPrefs(pref); 
        }
        else {
            // Player is alive, do whatever you want, or do nothing at all.
        }
    }
    else {
        // if it's not set, just create it.
        resetPrefs(pref);
    }

    // ...   
}

private void resetPrefs(SharedPreferences pref) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
    editor.putInt(PREF_LIFES, 6);
    editor.putInt(PREF_HINTS, 6);          
    editor.putInt(PREF_LEVEL, 1);
    editor.putBoolean(PREF_IS_SET,true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

**EDIT 2:** You can put this logic on your `onResume()` method as well, as long as you remove it from the `onCreate()`, otherwise you'll be checking those conditions twice ;)

Comment: ok so the problem is because i put the Sharedpreferences onCreate method, so whats code should i change to make sharedpreferences work correctly? can you show me the repair of my code with an explain of the code?

Comment: You can keep it on the onCreate() with some adjustments. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: @Chairizky Take a look now. And that's not the only way to solve it. It depends on what behavior you want to achieve on your game.

Comment: Actually, you could do that there instead of doing it on the `onCreate()`. Might even be better, because it'll check for your game status every time the user resume the `Activity`.

Comment: oh ok, so i can put onResume() in else? at this else line //Player is alive, do whatever you want, or do nothing at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87177/discussion-between-mauker-and-chairizky).

Answer (score 4):

You have the following lines in your `onCreate` method :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
editor.putInt("Lifes", 6);
editor.putInt("Hints", 6);          
editor.putInt("Level", 1);  
editor.commit();
```

The `onCreate` method is run every time needed by the actvity lifecycle. Especially when openning the app. So everytime your activity is created you set the preference level to one. This is the reason of your issue.

Comment: so how to fix this condition sonic?

Comment: I think you should check whether the `pref` has been set or not.
If it has been set, do nothing. Otherwise, set the `pref`.

Comment: You can say like @Raymond Lukanta say. Or you can delete this line and set a default value to your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

i think you didn't check the existence values of shared Preferences in Menu.class.You just simply assign a default value without proper checking whether the sharedpreferences holds data or not.
In onCreate

try this one on OnCreate of Menu.class

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();   
//check it with your default value.I used default value as 0   
int lifes=pref.getInt("Lifes", 0);
if(lifes==0)
editor.putInt("Lifes", 6);
//check it with your default value.I used default value as 0 
 int hints=pref.getInt("Hints", 0);
 if(hints==0
 editor.putInt("Hints", 6);          
 //check it with your default value.I used default value as 0
  int level=pref.getInt("Level", 0);
  if(level==0)
  editor.putInt("Level", 1);  
  editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you start your app your menu.class reset or commit the shared preferences data by your code in menu.class file onCreate() like this :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
editor.putInt("Lifes", 6);
editor.putInt("Hints", 6);          
editor.putInt("Level", 1);  
editor.commit();
```

You need to check first if shared preferences already available with your shared preferences name, if no then initialise shared preferences code like this :

```
if() // Check your shared preferences already not available then initialise it
{
     SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
     editor.putInt("Lifes", 6);
     editor.putInt("Hints", 6);          
     editor.putInt("Level", 1);  
     editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you create your Activity, you are reseting your saved `Preferences`:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
editor.putInt("Lifes", 6);
editor.putInt("Hints", 6);          
editor.putInt("Level", 1);  
editor.commit();
```

You should only save your `Preferences` when they are changed.